# Is there anyway to find the PID of parent process without using getppid?

Tags: linux, parent, pid

I know that the PCB is a data structure which includes parent
process id(pPID), process id(PID), pointers, and etc. Is there anyway
to find the PID of parent process without using getppid function?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `getppid()`?  What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The fields of `/proc/self/stat` (as documented in [proc(5)](https://manpages.debian.org/proc.5.html)) include PPID. Take care in parsing as `comm` may contain spaces and other unusual characters.

(But I second @JohnZwinck's comment. Why?)

Comment: To find a way to imply 'getppid'-like system call in a new shell which the getppid function is not implemented yet.